# javascript username validation

Tags: javascript

What would be a good regex to use for validating a username, forbidding all special chars except the "@" symbol in case people want to use their email address as their username?

Comment: Just a reminder, you should also validate on the server-side, because a malicious user could bypass your Javascript validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+@){0,1}([a-zA-Z0-9.])+$
```

This will permit A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and ., and at most one @

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess this may work for your circumstances (see below)...

```
var userRegex = /^[\w\.@]{6,100}$/;
```

This will match...

- word characters such as 0-9, A-Z, a-z, _
- literal period
- literal @
- between 6 and 100 characters long

You should probably look at the [Email RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322), which states, amongst other characters, that the following are legal: ``` ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ `` { | } ~ ```. This means that the regex above will not allow all emails.

So...

```
var validUsername = document.getElementById('username').value.match(userRegex);
```